# How to get and append table contents if a specific class is found

Tags: jquery

I am wanting to get/append the contents of the tbody of a table , only when the caption span has an a class of "myfranchise"

Existing html

```
<table>
    <caption>
        <span>
         <a class="myfranchise"></a> <!-- Must have this class or do nothing -->
        </span>
    </caption>
    <tbody>       <!-----  GET ALL TR DATA BELOW  ------>
        <tr><th>Player</th><th>Week 1 Opponent</th></tr>
        <tr><td><a>TEXT</a></td><td>TEXT</td></tr>
        <tr></tr>
        <tr></tr>
        <tr></tr>
        <tr></tr>
        <tr></tr>
    </tbody>      <!-----  GET ALL TR DATA ABOVE  ------>
</table>
```

Here is what i have so far , but i dont know how to write the statement in the find () to get a just the tbody contents if the a class "myfranchise" is found.

```
    $.get('myurl', function (data) {
      $(data).find('??????').appendTo('#mystarters tbody');
    });


<table id="mystarters">
 <tbody>
        <!-----  APPEND ALL TR HERE  ------>
  </tbody>
</table>
```

Comment: What does the data received from $.get looks like?

Comment: <tr><th>Player</th><th>Week 1 Opponent</th></tr>  is an example of the tr content

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's a way to do it:

```
$.get('myurl', function (data) {
    myfranchise = $(data).find('.myfranchise').first();

    if (myfranchise.length !== 0) {
        myfranchise
            .closest('table')
            .find('tbody tr')
            .clone()
            .appendTo('#mystarters tbody');
    }
});
```

Comment: Try this, I have edited and undeleted after I finally understood what you were after.

Comment: added original html to jsfiddle , and at very bottom added the html to append to  https://jsfiddle.net/gq81m556/3/

Answer (score 0):

try this :

```
     $.get('myurlhere', function (data) {
      var table = $(data).find('.report');
if(table){
      if(table.find('a').hasClass('myfranchise')){
           $('#mystarters tbody').append(table.find('tbody'));
      }
}
    });
```

Comment: https://jsfiddle.net/gq81m556/3/  the table with data showing , is the one with the myfranchise tag - i left the other blank for demo